# Xcode 4 - key binding option key, possible for you?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

In xcode 4, I can't bind the command "Shift Right" to `option+tab` key and "Shift left" to `option+shift+tab`. I'm using textmate and those commands are binded like this, so I would like the same setup in xcode 4... But for some reason, it adds the command key in my bind! so `option+tab` is replaced by `option+command+tab`.

A quick fix that I found was to overwrite the bind in the system preferences, but was wondering why Xcode won't let me use my bind?

Comment: I'm having this same problem, can you tell the instructions how you fixed it using system preferences? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, figured it out! For the rest of you, you can fix this by: Open `System Preferences` -> Open `Keyboard` -> Open `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab -> Open `Application Shortcuts` from the left -> Click the `+` sign to add a new binding -> For the `Application` field scroll all the way down and select `Other` and then find XCode from `/Developer/Applications/XCode` -> For Menu Title use `Shift Left` (and `Shift Right`) and specify the corresponding shortcut you want. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the developers can say for sure, but it likely has to do with the many meanings of the Tab key:

- generates a tab character
- used with command to switch between applications
- iterates over controls in windows and dialog boxes
- iterates over links in web browser

I think I missed a couple, too. Due to its size and position, the Tab key is a hot commodity. The specific combination you want to use probably conflicts with an established or planned use of Tab.

Comment: But then again I was able to overwrite it in the system preferences, I thought it would be the same :o